# how do i dynamically create pdfs on java/google app engine

Tags: pdf, dynamic

How can I create a PDF dynamically in a Java based Google App Engine application?

I want this to be done from a java-based application (I saw similar questions asked already but those were for Python based applications).

Regards,
Arvind.

Answer (score 2):

See [this](http://conorjpower.com/2010/01/11/pdf-generation-in-java/) for a write up of some options.

EDIT: http://pdfjet.com/ appears to be the only library that is fully AppEngine-compatible.

Comment: the post you link to also mentions PDFmyURL - this service also allows PDF generation icw Google Apps, by using the login functionality - see http://pdfmyurl.com/html-to-pdf-api#secure - disclosure: I work for the company that owns PDFmyURL